# c# Socket and TcpClient unable to receive data

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I have tried with both Socket and TcpClient fuctions and I'm unable to receive data after sending.

I'm connecting to a clock device and the goal is to send some commands to it and receive some response from it. This commands are recognize by the device and it should retrieve data according to it.

So I tried with Sockets with the following code:

```
private static string IP_ADDRESS    = "10.0.0.20";
private static Int32 IP_PORT        = 5010;
private static string TEXT_TO_SEND  = "(1,software)";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Socket mySocket     = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    IPAddress ip        = IPAddress.Parse(IP_ADDRESS);
    IPEndPoint ipEnd    = new IPEndPoint(ip, IP_PORT);

    mySocket.Connect(ipEnd);

    byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TEXT_TO_SEND);
    mySocket.Send(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length, SocketFlags.None);

    Console.WriteLine("Sending : " + TEXT_TO_SEND);

    byte[] b                = new byte[100];
    int k                   = mySocket.Receive(b);
    string text_received    = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b, 0, k);

    // ---- NEVER REACHES HERE ----
    Console.WriteLine("Receiving : " + text_received);
}
```

And also tried with TcpClient.

```
private static string IP_ADDRESS    = "10.0.0.20";
private static Int32 IP_PORT        = 5010;
private static string TEXT_TO_SEND  = "(1,software)";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpClient client        = new TcpClient(IP_ADDRESS, IP_PORT);
    NetworkStream nwStream  = client.GetStream();
    byte[] bytesToSend      = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TEXT_TO_SEND);

    nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
    nwStream.Flush();

    Console.WriteLine("Sending : " + TEXT_TO_SEND);

    byte[] bytesToRead      = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
    int bytesRead           = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
    string text_received    = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead);

    // ---- NEVER REACHES HERE ----
    Console.WriteLine("Receiving : " + text_received);
}
```

I receive no error and while debugging I see clearly that both code connect successfully to the machine (with the IP and Port provided) but yet doesn't retrieve any data.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code (well, nothing that would cause your immediate issue anyway). Are you sure the device is listening? Can you connect with e.g. telnet and send the command manually succesfully? Are you sure the command is correct? E.g. there might be additional message framing, like having to end a command with `\0` or `\r\n` or something like that.

Comment: Try to use packet capture like Wireshark, to detect whether your clock is responding or not.

Comment: @X EDIT: nvm, I found it..the response seems to be 0 bytes, which therefore means its not working.